# Transform field in document's array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to convert some fields from string to integer with aggregate pipelines in MongoDB.

These fields are nested in a document's array, so that they are handled as array too.

Below an example document:

```
{
    "_id": *****,
    "subject": "first",
    "items": [
        "item_id": "1",
        "ratings": {
            "count": 90,
            "value": "8",
        },
        "item_id": "2",
        "ratings": {
            "count": 75,
            "value": "9",
        },
    ]
}
```

I tried with `$convert` and `$map` (on `items.item_id` and `items.rating.value`) but I got the following results:

- `$convert`: cannot convert array to int
- `$map`: each field becomes an array itself holding values from all items:

```
{
    "subject": "first",
    "items": [
        "item_id": [1, 2],
        "ratings": {
            "count": 90,
            "value": [8, 9],
        },
        "item_id": [1, 2],
        "ratings": {
            "count": 75,
            "value": [8, 9],
        },
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `items` array,
- `$toInt` to convert value to integer type
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with modified fields value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                "ratings": {
                  count: "$$this.ratings.count",
                  value: { $toInt: "$$this.ratings.value" }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wE_k_PjuGk1)